# Passar token por query param

Tags: webrequest

Tenho uma aplicação que roda em uma porta e preciso chamar uma outra aplicação em outra porta, para passar um token.

Passar um token por query param na url é uma boa prática?

Exemplo: http://localhost:4200/auth?token=AquiVemMeuToken

Comment: O Problema é que desta forma o token fica vulnerável para que qualquer um possa intercepta-lo. Eu tenho a mesma situação que você, e acabei não conseguindo pensar em uma solução, porem meu site tem `https`

Comment: Mas sem a secret key, o token não fica inseguro. Estou usando JWT e sempre preciso de uma secret key para fazer alguma coisa, entende?

Comment: Sugiro que faça um teste, pegue o token e use ele em uma requisição fora de seu projeto cliente. Eu tenho as mesmas configurações que você, e no meu caso eu consegui acesso. Por isso optei pelo `https`, Eu tb fiz o meu token ter validade maxima de 24hs. Mas ainda continuo preocupado.